# Flirc / Kodi - messes with Kodi when viewing normal TV

Tags: kodi

I've got a Pi set up with Kodi into my TV.

I've got a flirc usb in the Pi that I've mapped the original Samsung TV remote to control the Pi.

This works fine, but when I swap to watch normal TV rather than using the Pi, as the Pi is still on, the remote is still being picked up and while I'm browsing normal TV, i'm clicking in and out of menu's.

Is there an easy way round this?  Or is it something a universal remote might fix?   I've never used one before, can you map the Pi under a separate button (like then you switch between TV / Sky / DVD etc) so that when on TV the Pi isn't affected?

Thanks!